# Can't get iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are many topics about it, but none of them worked. I need just to get iframe content(not source code).

I have a form, that posts some parameters to another server and I target it to iframe(that lies on the same page). So I receive server responce code storred in my iframe without page refresh:

```
<form name='vin_form' id='file_upload_form' action='*****' method='post'>
    <input name='name1' value='value1'>
    <input name='name2' value='value2' type='hidden'>
    <input name='name3' value='value3' type='hidden'>
    <div onclick=\"document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; document.vin_form.submit();\">Send form</div>
</form>";

<iframe id='upload_target' name='upload_target'></iframe>
```

To get iframe content I used everything, but nothing worked:

```
jQuery('#upload_target').load(function()
    {
            alert(jQuery('#upload_target').contents().find('body').html());

            var myIFrame = document.getElementById('upload_target');
            var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            alert(content);

            alert(window.frames.upload_target.document.body);
    }
);
```

I read about "same origin policy", but I think it shouldn't be forbidden in my case, because I can access that page by url and read all the code, so why I can't do it programmatically?

P.S.: Are there some other ways to get form responce code from another server? (php curl doesn't work because of some site framework defence)

Comment: Well, do both pages have the same origin? You say you think... you should check to make sure.

Comment: I agree with Šime, if you can access it by the URL then you're on that site and it's cool; if you load it from an iframe then you're not on the same origin unless both your site and the iframe's target are on the same domain.  It might help if you can clarify what you're actually hoping to achieve and why you're doing it this way.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browsers javascript console ?

Comment: Yes, error: "Permission denied to access property 'document'". Means that it is really forbidden... What I want to do is to get an html code from url page on another domain, but this url is protected and i cannot access it without form submit and posting some values. So what to do? :\

Answer (score 1):

*update - try this:

```
 var t = document.getElementById("upload_target");
 var y =( t.contentWindow || t.contentDocument);
 alert(y.document.body.innerHTML)
```

Comment: he's actually binding to the onload event of the iframe (jquery has two `.load()` methods). also, The ajax load method strips away `body` and `head` and those things -- if he had been using that, I mean.

Comment: @nbrooks i know they are two load method, i will remove the load part of the answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't work :( It handles error: "Permission denied to access property 'document'"